# Why is an integration test failing with "Test Error failing to assert “login_path”

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I am following MHartl tutorial and I have an integration test that fails yet the two other assertions based on the same page are passing.

The code I have is

```
 test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
```

The one assertion not working is

`assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path`

which raises the error

`Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/login"]", found 0`

However, the last two assertions are passing as expected.

```
assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
```

So if all three assertions test whether the logout redirects to the  homepage, why are the two passing while the test for *login_path* is failing?

Comment: Have a look at the HTML that is coming out of your app. Search for a link to a /login path (there won't be one there), then figure out why it's not there

Comment: Most likely a typo when making the link I'd imagine

Comment: Sounds like an idea, let me get to it. Thanks.

Comment: ...Or maybe the link is an absolute URL, not a relative URL. Or maybe there's a link to `/signup` (or similar) rather than `/login`. Or maybe the logout functionality doesn't actually work. Or maybe you've landed on a different page, with neither a login nor a logout link. Either way, to debug the problem, take a look at the HTML of the page.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord and Mark . So like you suggested Mark I looked at the HTML in the header.html.erb to confirm that indeed that there is a login_path. 
Sure enough the link had a stub and was not redirecting to login_path.

Comment: But I now need to check the tutorial and confirm whether I missed a step, or Mhartl did the assertion before filling in the Login Path. Thanks again you both have helped me learn something valuable about debugging, In addition to checking whether I have written the test correctly, I should look also look at the code of what is being tested whether model or view. Thanks again.